# How to Solve Lazy initialize Exception to get the list of data using hibernate Bidirectional One to Many Mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, one-to-many, lazy-initialization

Consider the following two tables - posts and comments of a Blog database schema where the posts table has a one-to-many relationship with the comments table

I'm using **Bidirectional One to Many Mapping**, because my child entities are limited only.

In **Bidirectional One to Many Mapping**, I wrote one rest call to get all the post with appropriate comments for the post Using default find all method in JPA Repository.

**But the following exception occurred:**

```
"message": "Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.insights.apartmento.modal.Post.comments, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.insights.apartmento.modal.Post.comments, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.insights.apartmento.modal.Post[\"comments\"])",
```

My Pojo class as follows

> ```
> In POST POJO
> ```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    @Size(max = 250)
    private String description;

    @Lob
    private String content;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "post")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

> In Comments POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    // Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `@OneToMany` association gets fetched lazily, which should always be your [preferred `FetchType`](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/entity-mappings-introduction-jpa-fetchtypes/). It performs much better than EAGER fetching.

But then you need to make sure that you initialize all required associations before you close the `Session` or send the entity object to any client. In your case, the JSON marshaling happens after your Session got closed, which caused the exception.

There are [multiple ways to initialize a lazily fetched association](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/). The easiest one is a JOIN FETCH clause in a JPQL query, e.g.:

```
SELECT p FROM Post p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.comments c WHERE p.id = :id
```

If you're using em.find to load the Post entity, you either need to replace it with a [JPQL query](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpql/) or [use an `EntityGraph`](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serialize directly the `Post` Object. What happens is that Jackson marshaller tries to build a JSON from the full class, included the `private Set<Comment> comments`

Since you are using a Lazy FetchType (correctly according to me) Hibernate will throw a `LazyInitializationException` 
You can avoid this in several way:

1. You can ignore the `comments` Set in the generated JSON by using the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on this property
2. You can fully load the Post object but using a different `FetchType` (e.g `EAGER` or `JOIN`)
3. You can use the `Hibernate.initialize` method

Which solution to use? Well this depends on your use case. In any case I strongly suggest you to avoid the solution number 2 (fully load the Post object but using a different `FetchType` (e.g. `EAGER` or `JOIN`) because this means you'll always load Posts with all comments and this is very impactful on performance

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably not running with a transaction boundary defined. With lazy loading, you need to define at least a read-only transaction if you want to walk the graph and retrieve child records this way.
The "no session" is the hint here. Wrap your service class call in the @Transactional and all will be well.
Define read-only if you don't need to do any updates.

Answer (score -3):

In one to many mapping, define fetch type as EAGER.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "post")
```

Comment: Please don't use `FetchType.EAGER`. It forces Hibernate to always fetch the associated entities, even if you don't need them. That's one of the [most common performance pitfalls](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/common-hibernate-mistakes-cripple-performance) with JPA and Hibernate.